# PhoneGap or Adobe Air for porting existing HTML5 web app to iPad?

Tags: mobile, cordova, air

We are developing a web application using HTML5/JS + Backbone.js and jQuery. Release 1 is for browsers on desktop/laptop only. Next release needs to be deployed also on iPads. So we need to decide on a wrapper framework for porting our web app to an installable app (.ipa).

We want to reuse as much code as possible and right now we are considering **PhoneGap** and **Adobe Air**. Requirements are:

- Access to device file system (content > 300 mb)
- Access to real DB
- Support for video and audio playback
- Good support for HTML5 and CSS3
- Fast, responsive touch interface - important! (swipe, scroll, flip)

What are the pros and cons of each framework?